# Advanced book multivariate statistics

Tags: clustering, pca, multivariate-analysis, references, partial-least-squares

I am looking for a somewhat advanced book on multivariate statistics. I don't mind if there is a lot of math in it, and I prefer R above SPSS. I'm looking specifically for a book that mentions PCA, partial least squares, cluster analysis and multiple factor analysis. So basically a book that combines PCA and cluster analysis for a mix of categorical data and continuous data. I know about some multivariate statistics books, but none really mention these kinds of methods. Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

ISL and ESL books are classical ones for machine learning people. Both free online, and with R code.

[An Introduction to Statistical Learning](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5ff2adbe3fe4fe33db902812/t/6062a083acbfe82c7195b27d/1617076404560/ISLR%2BSeventh%2BPrinting.pdf)

[The Elements of Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf)